# How to display build time in ISO format with spring boot maven plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I would like to display the build time in ISO 8601 format ('yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ') in my actuator info endpoint. The build info is generated by the spring-boot-maven-plugin.

It is a spring boot project but we have configure a lot of things by hand because the project does not a spring boot parent child project, we have to use a different parent. So maybe I miss out something.

My actuator endpoint on `localhost:9090/actuator/info` contains the following build info:

```json
"build:{
  "artifact":"application",
  "name":"application",
  "time":1657089305.677000000,
  "version":"0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "group":"my.group"
 }
```

In my `application.yml` I use the following configuration:

```
management:
  server:
    port: 9090
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: health,info
  info:
    build:
      enabled: true
    java:
      enabled: true
    git:
      enabled: true
```

In my `pom.xml` I use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in the following way:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>build-info</goal>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this configuration, the plugin will generate a `build-info.properties` file based on the Maven project. This file will be used by the actuator which is fine. The [plugin's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.3/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-repackage-parameters-details-outputTimestamp) tells about the build info time property the following:

> outputTimestamp Timestamp for reproducible output archive entries,
> either formatted as ISO 8601 (yyyy-MM-dd’T’HH:mm:ssXXX) or an int
> representing seconds since the epoch.

Update:
I have tried out setting maven property but it does not helped me:

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

It is fine but how should I configure it to use the ISO format instead of this epoch?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps if you want to do it in a custom way:

Add this into your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
   <build.timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</build.timestamp>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

and then reference it via:

```
info:
   build-timestamp: @build.timestamp@
```

Comment: Thank you for your input but I would like to know how can I set the build timestamp format used by spring boot maven plugin.